# jQuery как дополнить скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть скрипт jquery.pep.js как его дополнить событием 'клик левой' кнопки мыши, кто может помочь? ну и соответственно как его привязать к событию?

Comment: `element.addEventListener('click', function () {...` - добавит событие 'клик левой' по `element`

Comment: надеюсь, это то что вам нужно.